# Android - pass large amount of data to service running on a different process

Tags: android, aidl

is there any possible way to pass a large amount of data into an Android Service that runs on a different process from the main activity?
The data to pass is a byte array of around 5Mb.
As notes, I cannot save the data to file to do the transfer, needs to be transferred purely via memory or any other way which isn't to persist to file, databases, etc.

I've tried via AIDL, but seems in Android under AIDL the parcelable data is limited 1Mb. Also slicing the data and transferring it via chunks is not an option. Should be 1 single transaction.
I've also tried Intents, but again the same limitations of 500Kb to 1Mb.

So I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Why are you using a separate process in the first place?

Comment: For 2 reasons, first to offload work that can consume the main activity heap, and second because the user can stop the main process by exiting the app, but the processing might not be completed yet. The app can queue several jobs, which each could take several seconds. By using another process I have the advantage of having a different heap which doesn't reduce the one from the main activity, plus I offload all the work to a process that can keep working until completed, without forcing the user to wait for each job to complete, and even allow to exit the app if he wants without having to wait

Comment: You do not need a separate process to "keep working until completed, without forcing the user to wait for each job to complete, and even allow to exit the app if he wants without having to wait".

Comment: I know that I could keep a service in the background running in the same process, but still have the problem of the heap. The jobs are for large image processing at complete full resolution, so there is no option to decode at smaller sizes for processing. If I decode a large image in the main activity which already has heap allocated to run itself, then I will get from time to time a outofmemory exception. Pushing the processing to a different process (which has the benefit of having its own heap) I also avoid the memory restriction problem, as the service only works exclusively for processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about shared memory ashmem 
http://www.androidenea.com/2010/03/share-memory-using-ashmem-and-binder-in.html

Memory file is an ashmem wrapper
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html

Or you could try opening a socket or ServerSocket in your service and connecting to it from your activity

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: The second option, Memory File seems to be what I am looking for.