# Get access to MemoryFile from Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

My idea is when the user closes the application I want to save a custom file format that includes a image that the user previously opened, and some other properties inside that custom file. To store the image and every other property I use Bytes. The file have to be stored when the method **[onPause()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause)** is called, this is the method the Android team suggest to store any data.

Since code run inside method **[onPause()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause)** is executed on the main thread and the method is called when the user is about to close the application. But what if then he decides to go back to the application, and since the file is big and all the code is done on the main thread the UI freezes. I cannot run the code in to a separate thread, because if the user closes the   application and the thread get destroyed before his work is save, it will be lost.

The pixels for the image are stored as [ByteArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte-array/) , and the overall memory for the array is around 3-7 MB

To keep saving the file on separate thread even when the application is already destroyed I use **[ForegroundService](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)**, with message to the user that his work is now being saved. The problem comes when I try to save the ByteArray, since it is a large in size 3-7 MB and there is limitation when using parcelable data.

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616811/android-pass-large-amount-of-data-to-service-running-on-a-different-process), and there was a suggestion to use [Memory File](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html). I manage to access the byte array in the service, but to do that I first created a Bundle and then add Binder to it. The binder have a method that gives access to the memory file. I have two questions, my first question is if that is the correct way to do it? And my second question is if there are better way to transfer large arrays from activity/fragment to a service with some example code if possible?

Here is the code for class SaveProjectService:

```
class SaveProjectService : Service() {

    abstract class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        abstract fun getMemoryFile(): MemoryFile
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        val bitmapInfo = intent.getBundleExtra("imageBundle")
        if (bitmapInfo != null) {

            val memoryFile = (bitmapInfo.getBinder("imageBinder") as LocalBinder).getMemoryFile()
            val byteArray = memoryFile.inputStream.readBytes()  // here I manage to get the array values
            memoryFile.close()
        }
       
        thread {
           // here I save the file
        }

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Here is the code for creating the service in MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        
        // create intent
        val serviceIntent = Intent(context, SaveProjectService::class.java)

        // create memory file
        val memoryFile = MemoryFile("image", helper.bitmapInfo.last().bitmapByteBufferData.size)
        memoryFile.outputStream.write(helper.bitmapInfo.last().bitmapByteBufferData)

        // create binder object that return the memory file
        val binder = object : SaveProjectService.LocalBinder() {
               override fun getMemoryFile(): MemoryFile {
                     return memoryFile
               }
        }

        // set binder->bundle->service
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putBinder("imageBinder", binder)
        serviceIntent.putExtra("imageBundle", bundle)
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context!!, serviceIntent)

        super.onPause()
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: Did you try a thread? I would think that would be ok.

Comment: Yes, it work I get the proper ByteArray in the service, but I am not sure if that is the proper way to do it. And I don't know if there is probability of memory leaks or some other proplems! The documentation is very poorly written...

Comment: For example if I do some heavy operations for too long, and I use ordinary thread. I think once the application get destroyed there is probability for the thread getting destroyed before the saving of the file is finished.

Comment: Well test it i would say.

Comment: Well for memory leaks I have tried LeakCanary but even when I intentionally create memory leak to test it I don't receive any messages that a memory leak was detected. Are there any other easy way to detect memory leaks?

Comment: Why would there be a memory leak if you used a thread to create a file?